# Can't compile C++ plug-ins with OSX Lion?

Tags: c++, plugins, maya

I have been writing a plug-in for Maya with C++. The `Makefile` I use works fine on Snow Leopard, but does not in Lion. I am using the latest version of Maya 2012 in both cases. Here's the top of the error stack:

```
/Applications/Autodesk/maya2012/Maya.app/Contents/../../devkit/include/maya/OpenMayaMac.h:89:35: error: 
    AvailabilityMacros.h: No such file or directory
/Applications/Autodesk/maya2012/Maya.app/Contents/../../devkit/include/maya/OpenMayaMac.h:107:24: error: 
    sys/param.h: No such file or directory
/Applications/Autodesk/maya2012/Maya.app/Contents/../../devkit/include/maya/OpenMayaMac.h:114:40: error: 
    CoreServices/CoreServices.h: No such file or directory
```

This makes me think that these files are in a different location in Lion, but I do see them all in my /usr/include/ directory, just like Snow Leopard. Anyone have similar issues, ideas, suggestions?

The make file I use is below:

```
# NOTE: MAYA_LOCATION on Mac OS X points to Maya.app/Contents
MAYA_LOCATION = /Applications/Autodesk/maya2012/Maya.app/Contents

# Change location if a non standard install.
DEVKIT_LOCATION = $(MAYA_LOCATION)/../../devkit

C++ =  g++

PREFERRED_ARCHITECTURE =

# Determine the architectures to build.
MAYABIN = ${MAYA_LOCATION}/bin/maya
MAYA_ARCHES = $(shell lipo -info $(MAYABIN) | sed 's/^.*://')

ifneq ($(PREFERRED_ARCHITECTURE),)
    MAYA_ARCHES = $(filter $(PREFERRED_ARCHITECTURE),$(MAYA_ARCHES))

    ifeq ($(MAYA_ARCHES),)
        $(error $(MAYABIN) does not support the '$(PREFERRED_ARCHITECTURE)' architecture.)
    endif
endif

ARCH_FLAGS =    $(patsubst %,-arch %,$(MAYA_ARCHES))

CFLAGS =    -DAW_NEW_IOSTREAMS -DCC_GNU_ -DOSMac_ -DOSMacOSX_ \
        -DOSMac_MachO_ -DREQUIRE_IOSTREAM -fno-gnu-keywords -fpascal-strings -O3 \
        $(ARCH_FLAGS) -D_LANGUAGE_C_PLUS_PLUS -isysroot /Developer/SDKs/MacOSX10.6.sdk \
        -include $(MAYA_LOCATION)/../../devkit/include/maya/OpenMayaMac.h \
        -shared

C++FLAGS =  $(CFLAGS)

INCLUDES =  -I. -I$(MAYA_LOCATION)/../../devkit/include

LDFLAGS =   -framework Carbon -framework OpenGL -framework GLUT -lOpenMayaUI

LD =        $(MAYA_LOCATION)/../../devkit/bin/mayald MAYA_ARCHES="$(MAYA_ARCHES)" MAYA_LOCATION="$(MAYA_LOCATION)"


all: VmExample.bundle


VmExampleNode.o: VmExampleNode.cpp 
    $(C++) -c VmExampleNode.cpp $(C++FLAGS) $(INCLUDES)

vmPluginMain.o: vmPluginMain.cpp
    $(C++) -c vmPluginMain.cpp $(C++FLAGS) $(INCLUDES)

VmExample.bundle: VmExampleNode.o vmPluginMain.o
$(LD) -dynamic -bundle -o VmExample.bundle VmExampleNode.o vmPluginMain.o ../core/libVexample.o $(LDFLAGS)
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

same problem here; Managed to make it work by adding
-mmacosx-version-min=10.6 
-isysroot /Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer/Platforms/MacOSX.platform/Developer/SDKs/MacOSX10.6.sdk

to C++ Flags

Comment: Thanks for the reply, pretty much worked with your change - I can't remember exactly what else I had to do at the time, but it was very minimal.